# Parameterize font name in \newfontfamily

Tags: luatex, fontspec

I would like to create a command that makes a new font family.  But I cannot get the `\newfontfamily` command to work with a parameterized font name.  I am using Lualatex.

What can I do to get `\newfontfamily` to work inside the `\mkfnt` command?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\newcommand\mkfnt[3]{%
  \defaultfontfeatures[#2]{
    UprightFont    = LinLibertine_R ,
    ItalicFont     = LinLibertine_RI ,
    BoldFont       = LinLibertine_R#3 ,
    BoldItalicFont = LinLibertine_R#3I ,
    Extension      = .otf
  }
  %\newfontfamily\#1{#2}        % Want to create font family here
}

\mkfnt{mylib}{mylibD}{B}
\newfontfamily\mylib{mylibD}    % Want to eliminate this line

\begin{document}
Hello
{\mylib Hello in Libertine}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\expandafter\newfontfamily\csname#1\endcsname` not `\newfontfamily\#1` or use `\newfontfamily#1` and `\mkfnt{\mylib}{mylibD}{B}`

Comment: Hah! I'd tried playing with `\csname`, but didn't have the `\expandafter`.  Thanks!

Comment: You don't want to use `\defaultfontfeatures`, but the optional argument to `\newfontfamily`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The token `\#` just typesets `#` it is not related to the macro parameter use.

You want `\expandafter\newfontfamily\csname#1\endcsname` not `\newfontfamily\#1` or use `\newfontfamily#1` and `\mkfnt{\mylib}{mylibD}{B}`

I would probably use the latter syntax so the command being defined, `\mylib` is explicit in the definition call, but it is just a matter of taste.

Answer (score 2):

I see no reason for this approach: calling

```
\mkfnt{\mylib}{mylibD}{B}
```

is as easy and it also would check for the command being defined. On the other hand, there's a much simpler way.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\newcommand\mkfnt[2]{%
  \newfontfamily#1{LinLibertine}[
    UprightFont    = *_R,
    ItalicFont     = *_RI,
    BoldFont       = *_R#2,
    BoldItalicFont = *_R#2I,
    Extension      = .otf,
  ]%
}

\mkfnt{\mylib}{B}

\begin{document}

Hello

{\mylib Hello in Libertine}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's the relevant part of the log file:

```
Package fontspec Info: Font family 'LinLibertine(0)' created for font
(fontspec)             'LinLibertine' with options [UprightFont =
(fontspec)             *_R,ItalicFont = *_RI,BoldFont = *_RB,BoldItalicFont =
(fontspec)             *_RBI,Extension = .otf].
```